# How to categorize data as others if training set is not available?

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, cart, decision-theory

I run into a problem. I am using the decision tree to classify the incident category based on the short description the user has used while logging the ticket.

I have the training data only for 5 most recurring categories and want to identify how many new incidents(which has, lets say 8 categories) are falling only in these 5 buckets. I don't care about remaining 3 categories.

How can i create a category as others (will it be just a 6th category ) for which i have to get the training data ? Do we have any approach to handle such issues ?

Answer (score 0):

You can  **label 6th category as 'Other' or 'Unlisted'**  or something else and then create the data for training.

**1. Trial and Error approach:**
 Generate data and test if this falls into one of the 5 categories.
 If yes, discard.
 If no, add it to the training set for the 6th category.
This can be  *time consuming*  since you are generating data randomly without any information about your training set.

**2. A better and a scientific way:** 
  For each category, get the probability distribution of the data
  Generate data with the distribution that your training data hasn't covered. This will be a bit certain. To generate data according to a distribution you can use numpy.random which supports all the known distributions:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/routines.random.html#distributions